# How to resolve InvalidSelectorException of Xpath in testng?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, xpath, testng

code :-

public class CarServiceInfoPage {
public Object[][] carServiceInfoPage(WebDriver driver,ExtentTest test,ExtentReports extent) throws IOException {

```
    int flag = 0;
    String b = "";
    int rowCount = 1;
    
    
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("CarService CenterData");
    
    Object[][] obj = new Object[20][3];
    obj[0][0] = "Name";
    obj[0][1] = "Address";
    obj[0][2] = "PhoneNumber";
    
    
    Object[][] output = new Object[10][3];
    int outputrow = 0; 
    
    try {
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("store-details"));
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String[] phone = null;
        String phoneString = null;
        String[] stringArray = new String[0];
        int j = 0;
        float rat[]=new float[elements.size()]; 
        for(int i=0;i<elements.size();i++) {
            String temp =elements.get(i).findElement(By.className("green-box")).getText();
            rat[i]= Float.parseFloat(temp);
            String Vote = elements.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"bcard"+i+"\"]/div[1]/section/div[1]/p[1]/a/span[3]")).getText();
            String numberOnly= Vote.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
            int VoteInteger = Integer.parseInt(numberOnly);
            List<WebElement> PhoneNumberString =  driver.findElements(By.className("mobilesv"));
            if(flag == 0) {
                for(int k = 0;k<PhoneNumberString.size();k++) {
                    phoneString = PhoneNumberString.get(k).getAttribute("class").split("-")[1];
                    MobileClass r = new MobileClass();
                    String temp2 = r.mobileClass(phoneString);
                    b += temp2;
                }
                flag = 1;
                while(j<b.length()) {
                    if(b.charAt(j) == '0') {
                        int count = 0;  
                        String var = "";
                        while(j<b.length() && count <= 10) {
                            var += b.charAt(j); 
                            j++;count++;
                        }
                        stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(stringArray,stringArray.length+1);
                        stringArray[stringArray.length - 1] = var;
                    }
                    else if(b.charAt(j) == '+') {
                        int count = 0;
                        String var = "";
                        while(j<b.length() && count <= 15) {
                            var += b.charAt(j); 
                            j++;count++;
                        }
                        stringArray = Arrays.copyOf(stringArray,stringArray.length+1);
                        stringArray[stringArray.length - 1] = var;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(rat[i]>=4.0 && VoteInteger > 20) {
                output[outputrow][0] = elements.get(i).findElement(By.className("lng_cont_name")).getText();
                obj[rowCount][0] = elements.get(i).findElement(By.className("lng_cont_name")).getText();
                
                output[outputrow][1] = elements.get(i).findElement(By.className("cont_sw_addr")).getText();
                obj[rowCount][1] = elements.get(i).findElement(By.className("cont_sw_addr")).getText();
                
                output[outputrow][2] = stringArray[i];
                obj[rowCount][2] = stringArray[i];
                rowCount++;
            }
            outputrow++;
        }
        
        test = extent.createTest("Car Service Info Searching");
        
        test.log(Status.INFO, "This step shows usage of log,info");
        test.info("This test shows searching car wash service and printing on Console");
        test.pass("Passed",MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath("screenshot3.png").build());
        
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        test.fail("Failed",MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath("screenshot3.png").build());
    }
    int rows = obj.length;
    int cols = obj[0].length;
    
    
    for(int k=0;k<rows;k++) {
        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(k);
        for(int p=0;p<cols;p++) {
            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(p);
            Object value = obj[k][p];
            if(value instanceof String) {
                cell.setCellValue((String)value);
            }
            if(value instanceof Integer) {
                cell.setCellValue((Integer)value);
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    String filePath = "./ExcelReport/JustDialService.xlsx";
    FileOutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    workbook.write(outstream);
    outstream.close();
    workbook.close();
    
    return output;
}
```

}

error :-

org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id='bcard'0']/div[1]/section/div[1]/p[1]/a/span[3] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id='bcard'0']/div[1]/section/div[1]/p[1]/a/span[3]' is not a valid XPath expression.
(Session info: chrome=101.0.4951.67)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 101.0.4951.67, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 101.0.4951.41 (93c720db8323..., userDataDir: C:\Users\welcome\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:53349}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: afe3a97929dbe540e60ed0c502834e77
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id='bcard'0']/div[1]/section/div[1]/p[1]/a/span[3]}

Comment: When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is referred to by community members as creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

*Try* this `xpath`

```
"//*[@id='bcard'"+i+"]/div[1]/section/div[1]/p[1]/a/span[3]"
```

Instead of

```
"//*[@id=\"bcard"+i+"\"]/div[1]/section/div[1]/p[1]/a/span[3]"
```

in the below line

```
String Vote = elements.get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"bcard"+i+"\"]/div[1]/section/div[1]/p[1]/a/span[3]")).getText();
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error:-


org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id='bcard'0]/div[1]/section/div[1]/p[1]/a/span[3] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id='bcard'0]/div[1]/section/div[1]/p[1]/a/span[3]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=101.0.4951.67)

Comment: Add the HTML source for this element